# Apache Configuration. Magento Your web server is configured incorrectly

Tags: configuration, server-setup, apache, local

Right now I am facing some problems with my **web server** running Magento CE 1.9.2.1. In adminhtml I do get the security message, that says my web server seems to be **configured incorrectly**.

I’ve done almost everything to solve the problem. The answer of this post seems to be the most common solution for everybody  ([Apache Configuration local.xml warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492039/magento-apache-configuration-app-etc-local-xml-accessible-warning))

I’ve checked the **.htaccess** files in **root, app, var, lib** etc. and everything will be blocked correctly with a 403 by .htaccess if one tries to get those data through the webserver (like **BASE-URL/app/etc/local.xml**). I do also get a new entry in my apache log that says, that the access was (successfully) denied by server configuration.

In the **default server configuration, vhost configuration and .htaccess** I made sure, that I entered

```
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
for the <Directory "srv/www/htdocs"></Directory>
```

My **file permissions** were set to

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 mage
chmod 550 cron.sh
chmod 550 app/etc/local.xml (also tried 644 and 600)
chmod 550 app/etc/config.xml (also tried 644 and 600)
```

I do still get this security message in my backend. Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

if you able to open your `app/etc/local.xml` then there is something wrong with `.htaccess` rules.

just to make sure add this to your apache config:

```
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/>
        Options -Indexes
</Directory>

<LocationMatch /(app|includes|pkginfo|var)/>
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(sh|pl|phar|conf|sql)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory ~ /(media|shell|skin|lib)/>
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<LocationMatch /\.(svn|git|hg|gitignore)/?>
Require all denied
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch /cron\.php$>
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Just to make sure: I am **not** able to open app/etc/local.xml through the browser from the beginning. This is the expected behavior. But the error in admin html is still present.

Comment: then internal server connection is allowed/granted somewhere in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the same problem, the Apache is executed after nginx.

To test the problem I had searched the code that test it and I found it:

```
private function _isFileAccessible()
{
    $defaultUnsecureBaseURL = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL);
    $http = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
    $http->setConfig(array('timeout' => $this->_verificationTimeOut));
    $http->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $defaultUnsecureBaseURL . $this->_filePath);
    $responseBody = $http->read();
    $responseCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($responseBody);
    $http->close();

    return $responseCode == 200;
}
```

Then I changed to it:

```
$defaultUnsecureBaseURL = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL);
$defaultUnsecureBaseURL = "<URL TO UNSECURE BASE URL>";
$_verificationTimeOut = 150;
$_filePath = 'app/etc/local.xml';
$http = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
$http->setConfig(array('timeout' => $_verificationTimeOut));
$http->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $defaultUnsecureBaseURL . $_filePath);
$responseBody = $http->read();
$responseCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($responseBody);
$http->close();
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array($defaultUnsecureBaseURL.$_filePath,$responseCode));
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array($responseBody));
echo "</pre>";
```

With it I got the response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <URL TO UNSECURE BASE URL>/app/etc/local.xml
    [1] => 200
)
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 04:44:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
)
```

With this new information someone knows what to do?